# Next problem with wlan0

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 14 and can't connect to WiFi. Tried to find solutions by myself but still things don't work out.

Steps I have taken:

1. Went to `Software And Updates` -> `additional Drivers` and used **Broadcom 802.11 Linux drivers**
2. Used `iwconfig` command, found that `wlan0` doesn't exists
3. Installed `linux-firmware-nonfree` package  - `wlan0` shows now up

After these steps I still can't connect to network and I'm getting following error in toolbar:

> ```
> WiFi is disabled by hardware switch.
> ```

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508]
 Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: [code]02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508]
 Kernel driver in use: wl[/code]

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 1):

You have installed a wrong driver for this adapter.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe b43
```

and your Wi-Fi should work.